# How to list quickly files or folders in Android like pre-installed Gallery or Music app

Tags: android, algorithm, gallery, loading

I'm trying to make gif viewer App in Android.
I want to load files as fast as Gallery App(Manufacturer app) does.
As you know these apps list all my folders or image files just in 1 second.
But My code take about 10 seconds to search all files and folders in my phone.

Below is my code.

```
class InitialTask extends AsyncTask<File, String, ArrayList<Gif_Get_Set>>{
    ArrayList<Gif_Get_Set> arrayList;

    public InitialTask() {
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Gif_Get_Set> doInBackground(File... params) {
        String path = "";
        int i=0;
        File[] file = params[0].listFiles();
        while(i<file.length){

            if(file[i].canRead()){
                Log.d("Async", file[i].getPath());
                Search(file[i]);

            }

            i++;

        }

        return this.arrayList;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Gif_Get_Set> arrayList) {
       if(progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()){
           progressDialog.dismiss();
       }

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
       progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Loading", "Please Wait...", true, true, new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
           @Override
           public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
               finish();
           }
       });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        progressDialog.setMessage(values[0]);
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    private void Search(File file){

        File[] files = file.listFiles();

        Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(File lhs, File rhs) {
                return lhs.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(rhs.getName());
            }
        });


        for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++){

                if (files[i].isFile()) {

                    if (files[i].getName().endsWith(".gif") || files[i].getName().endsWith(".GIF")) {
                        Gif_Get_Set gif_get_set = new Gif_Get_Set(files[i], file.getName());
                        publishProgress(files[i].getPath());
                        arrayList.add(gif_get_set);
                    }


                } else if (files[i].isDirectory()) {


                    Search(files[i]);


                }

             Log.d("KKKK", files[i].getPath());
            }



        }

    }
```

I used AsyncTask to show Dialog during searching.

Please let me know if you have a good solution.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve the user experience by caching data. Load data only once per session and store it in a `static WeakHashMap container` and refer from this for future calls.

Reason for suggesting `WeakHashMap` over normal `Maps` is they use `WeakReference` and can be `garbage collected` if no one else is holding reference onto them.

**Update: You can also do this loading once only in Splash Screen which will make experience even seamless and better.**

Refer: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html